# How to fetch Parent and Child2 data from Child1 standard controller?

Tags: controller, salesforce, relationship, visualforce, soql

In the Org , we have 2 child objects Linked with Parent (Namely Child1 & Child2)

We have used standard controller for child1.

Now we have to fetch Parent data and Child2 data into VF page.

In Order to met the requirement. How should we code to fetch the Parent and Child 2 data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create a extension class for your VF page since standard controller only support ONE SOjbect.

For the Parent, the good new is that you can use `{!child1.Parent.Field_X__c}` to access it's fields. But you **HAVE TO** use custom extension class to fetch data for Child2.

[Custom Controllers and Controller Extensions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller.htm) shows details about extension, you may refer to it.